# How to make bottom area always visible on different screensizes?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm new here, and I have a specific question for a site i've designed.
It's build on a free wordpress theme called "Revera"

Is it possible to have the bottom part fixed to the bottom of the browserwindow. So that it's always visible, and there's no scrolling on the frontpage – no matter which screensize?

Here's the link:

http://dev.louderthanpepper.dk/

Hope anyone can help me
Soren

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `position:fixed`. This is what you are looking for. In your case it's `Footer class = fwidgets`

```
.fwidgets{ 
   position: fixed;
   background: #005b7f;
   border-top: 3px solid #f2f3f8;
   border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! So if i resize the browser window, this blue area with text will overlap the slider images, so it's always visible? Cause' that what i would like. Or does this require some editing in the slide area also?

Comment: Yes, in your case it would require some editting and make some other styling changes.